# Magento2 : Customer login not working properly

Tags: customer-account, magento-2.1.7

I have created multiwebsite magento site, and captcha is enabled on all forms.
But on the frontend customer login is not working properly.

Customer login form return `Incorrect Captcha` sometime even entering correct captcha and sometime it is working in first attempt.

Sometime it is returning error `maximum execution time exceeded`. And sometime customer logged-in successfully.

I'm stuck, where should I check for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the maximum execution time of the AJAX request of the Captcha has a timeout. You can fix that by increasing the `max_execution_time` setting in your PHP ini file.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded).

Comment: I already did, and added `max_execution_time` as 18000 and it is also reflecting in `phpinfo()` but still getting error `maximum execution time 60 seconds exceeded`. And also after this error customer showing as logged in only customer/account page is not loading.